Jackson serialize object property as escaped json string
I am trying to write a custom serializer to take a generic type, serialize it, and then add that json escaped as a string property.
Example
Having
class MyClass(
    val value : AType
)

//And AType serialized is:
"""
{
    "doloribus":false,
    "excepturi":false,
    "atque":-660028156
}
"""

//MyClass serialized is:
"""
{
  "value": {
    "doloribus": false,
    "excepturi": false,
    "atque": -660028156
  }
}
"""


Expecting
class MyClass(
    @field:JsonSerialize(using = ObjectAsEscapedStringSerializer::class)
    val value : AType
)

//MyClass serialized is:
"""
{
  "value": "{\"doloribus\":false,\"excepturi\":false,\"atque\":-660028156}"
}
"""

I have written this serializer but I dont fully like it:
class ObjectAsEscapedStringSerializer<T> : JsonSerializer<T>() {
    override fun serialize(value: T, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
        //I would like to serialize value without creating a new instance of objectMapper..
         val json = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
            disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        }.writeValueAsString(value)
        gen.writeString(json)
    }
}

TLDR
How can I serialize a generic value inside of a JsonSerializer without adding it to the generator?
or How can I use existing serializers/annotations to serialize an object as an escaped json string?
Thanks in advance.

For the 'how to remove objectmapper' question, your question is weird, what you did should not result in the serialized string you show, in fact you achieve the opposite (default is numeric, you make it a string by disabling WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS).
If you do in fact want a string just write a custom Date/Instant/... formatter and use that to generate the String, writing it with gen.writeString(). See https://www.baeldung.com/java-jackson-offsetdatetime#1-custom-serializer
As for the 'how to use existing serializers' question. Seems to me like you could achieve this by changing your class definition to be value: String, where the string is the default deserialized json string of AType. You can force this with a factory method taking an AType instance, and a private constructor. Of course your typing starts looking quite sketchy, so I would opt for the custom deserializer unless you got a good reason not to.

The object mapper in the example I put works, it serializes dates as ISO strings, which I expect/want. The issue I have with this is having to create an additional object mapper inside a custom serializer. I am looking to have the serialized version of AType (any type) as a string field in the json of the containing class.

As per the "how to use existing serializers" I meant how to use the parameter in the custom serializer SerializerProvider. According to the documentation I can use it ot fetch other serializers but I cant figure out how to get one for a generic type using this parameter
